# enum class with scoping but without having to cast to underlying type

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this:

```
enum class Categories : uint32_t {
    C6 = 0x00000020,
    C7 = 0x00000040,
    C8 = 0x00000080,
    ...
};
```

I chose an enum class because it is great for scoping. But the downside is that when I need to use the categories as mask bits for bitwise operations I need to cast them to uint32_t first.

Example:

`uint32_t masterCat = ((uint32_t)MyClass::Categories::C6) | ((uint32_t)MyClass::Categories::C7);`

**Is there a way I can get the same scoping benefit, without having to cast before using each time ?** If I use a regular enum, then I lose the scoping benefit :(

Example:

`uint32_t masterCat = (MyClass::Categories::C6) | (MyClass::Categories::C7);`

Comment: Related/dupe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23549280/convert-scoped-enum-to-int

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Split the `enum class` into an `enum` and a `class` (or `struct` for convenience).

```cpp
struct Categories {
    enum : uint32_t {
        C6 = 0x00000020,
        C7 = 0x00000040,
        C8 = 0x00000080,
    };
};
```

Since the `enum` is an embedded type, you need to specify `Categories` to access it, as in `Categories::C6`.

If this is inside another class, such as

```cpp
class MyClass {
  public:
    struct Categories {
        enum : uint32_t {
            C6 = 0x00000020,
            C7 = 0x00000040,
            C8 = 0x00000080,
        };
    };
};
```

then you can use `MyClass::Categories::C6` to refer to one of the enumerates, but neither `MyClass::C6` nor `C6` will work.

Comment: Could you omit `Enum` and just have `enum : uint32_t` inside `struct Categories`?

Comment: @Eugene that seems to work as well

Comment: @Eugene Oh right, thanks. I meant to check that before copying the code into an answer. (I couldn't remember if the identifier was required when the underlying type is specified, so I figured a first test should use it. Then I forgot to come back to it.)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use bitwise and still forbid conversion to its underlying type, then you might add functions, so cast is done only once, on purpose:

```
enum class Categories : std::uint32_t {
    C6 = 0x00000020,
    C7 = 0x00000040,
    C8 = 0x00000080,
    //...
};

constexpr /*Categories*/ std::uint32_t operator | (Categories lhs, Categories rhs)
{
    return /*Categories*/(std::uint32_t(lhs) | std::uint32_t(rhs));
}
// operator& ...
```